# How to count duplicate values in PIG

Tags: count, apache-pig

Im trying to count the number of memberids that are duplicated and have a count > 1 in a file with a list of ids.  I ran the below but got 1 value which i think is just counting the number of rows in the memberid column:

```
ids = load 'ids';
ids = filter ids by id;
group = group ids ALL;
count = foreach group generate count (ids);
dump count;
```

Comment: actually my file has 2 columns, an id column and a createdate column.  How do I only count the number of ids > 1 with a create date of 30 days from today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the file is tab delimited.

```
A = LOAD '/test.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id:int,create_dt:chararray);
B = FILTER A BY (id > 1 and DaysBetween(CurrentTime(),ToDate(create_dt)) == 30);
C = GROUP B BY id;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group as id,COUNT(B) as totalcount;
DUMP D;
```

Comment: thanks! actually the part im having issues with is your "B" below.  How do I modify this so that it only pulls Ids that are duplicates?  So for example if I have an ID as 2345, and "2345" appears 3 times in the file, i want this to get picked up in the output with a column for the ID number and the 2nd column being the number of time it appeared so for this example it would show "3" in the second column.

Comment: In your question comments you have asked for count ids > 1 and now you are asking for counting ids where the count is > 1.Just remove (id > 1 and ) from the 'B' filter.Then add E = FILTER D BY totalcount > 1;DUMP E;

Comment: @Tai. You are most welcome.Always post some sample data and desired output so that it is easier to understand.

Comment: Hi actually, i have one more question, when i run your "B" alias and filter on the last 30 days, im getting the below error.  It seems if i remove the last 30 day filter it works fine. Any thoughts on why i may be seeing this message? : "Unable to open iterator for alias blockcount. Backend error : Invalid format: "-26" is malformed at "26"